# Using assertEqual and getElementbyxpath in Junit Selenium

Tags: junit, selenium-webdriver

I'm basically writing a testcase to determine if a status shared on Facebook was actually shared. Below is the xpath for getting the text of first post on Facebook. I want to compare it to the status I posted e.g 'Blah'. I've been trying to use AssertEquals but that doesn't seem to be working.

```
 WebElement status = getElement(By.Xpath("//div[@id='pagelet_home_stream']//ul[@id = 'home_stream']//li[1]//span[@class='userContent']")

 AssertEquals(status, "Blah");
```

Comment: It may be a timing issue.

See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5817185/webdriver-cant-find-element-by-xpath

Comment: Can you show more of the code - e.g. the assertEquals(), how you obtain the value of the element. The XPath expression itself looks fine.

Comment: Added the AssertEquals statement.

Answer (score 3):

You need to call `element.getText()` otherwise you're comparing with a `WebElement` object rather than a `String`. Also, it's important that the expected text goes first in the assertEquals(expected, actual) otherwise you get a confusing message when they don't match.

```
assertEquals("Blah", status.getText());
```