# unable to perforn next action after performing one action in selenium webdriver . I was doing testing on trivago.com and below is my code

Tags: java, selenium

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='js-fullscreen-hero']/div/form/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/button")).click();
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10 ).ignoring(StaleElementReferenceException.class).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//*[@id='horus-shadowtext']")));
WebElement  ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='horus-shadowtext' and @class='horus__shadowtext']"));
List<String> windowlist = new ArrayList<String>();
windowlist.add(driver.getWindowHandle());
int si=  windowlist.size();
System.out.println(si);
Actions mouse2 = new Actions(driver);
mouse2.clickAndHold(ele).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,"china")).build().perform();
ele.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

after this it is unable to perform any steps not even the below step

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='js-fullscreen-hero']/div/form/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/button")).click();
```

can anyone please help me out with the proper solution.

Comment: Can you please sum up your exact manual steps you are trying to Automate? At which line are you seeing the error? Please update the error stack trace in the question area along with the relevant HTML. Thanks

Comment: Please describe **in words** the use case which you are trying to test. Also provide a [mcve]. Ideally this should be both the selenium test code as well as a very watered down version of the code you are trying to test.

Comment: below is the error log

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: .//*[@id='js-fullscreen-hero']/div/form/div[3]/div[2]/button
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'PEAMITRA', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver

Comment: It was able to locate the element when i have not used the control .

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
WebElementsource = driver.findElement(BylocatorType("path"));
```

Or

Use some effective techniques of choosing XPath by following links:

http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/choosing-effective-xpath/

For further exploration i would recommend another link

[WebDriver can't find element by xpath using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5817185/webdriver-cant-find-element-by-xpath-using-java)

I hope it will resolve your issue.

Thanks!

Comment: I have already tried with the above methods . But it is unable to perform any actions